# How to use Glide to load an array of images in an Adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-glide

With my current setup, it causes the RecyclerView to lag since I have a lot of resource images. How do I use Glide to load the array of images instead of **holder.item_img.setImageResource(INF.getImage_id());** in my ViewHolder?

```
ArrayList<Information> information = new ArrayList<Information>();
Context ctx;

public InformationAdapter(ArrayList<Information> information, Context ctx)
{
    this.information = information;
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

@Override
public InformationViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_layout,parent,false);
    InformationViewHolder informationViewHolder = new InformationViewHolder(view,ctx,information);
    return informationViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(InformationViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Information INF = information.get(position);
    holder.item_img.setImageResource(INF.getImage_id());
    holder.item_name.setText(INF.getName());
    holder.item_location.setText(INF.getLocation());

}

...
```

Comment: INF.getImage_id() : is your Image URL?

Comment: `Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(INF.getImage_id()).placeholder(R.drawable.your_placeholder).crossFade().into(holder.item_img);`

Comment: @Droidman I'm getting a cannot resolve method for getImage_i‌​d

Comment: @Janak I am loading the images from the drawable folder using int[] image_id in the mainactivity and public int getImage_id() { return image_id; }

Comment: @Bryant        Using this code  ( holder.item_img.setImageResource(INF.getImage_id()); ) are you able to show image?

Comment: @Janak Yes, the all the images load fine.

Comment: @Bryant         Glide.with(context)
    .load(R.id.resource_id)
    .into(holder.item_img);

Comment: @Janak I got it working using: Glide.with(ctx).load(information.get(position).getImage_id()).placeholder(R.drawable.loading).into(holder.item_img);

Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Glide.with(ctx)
    .load(information.get(position).getImage_id()‌​)
    .placeholder(R.draw‌​able.loading)
    .into(h‌​older.item_img);
```